# Is there an extension for vscode that let me view only the current function/block?

Tags: emacs, visual-studio-code

I am used to Emacs where I can choose to view (and edit) only one function in a view window (while simultaneusly viewing the whole file in another window).

Is there an extension for vscode that can do this?

Comment: I have no idea wrt tha specific request. By I am using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/itemdetails?itemName=elltg.open-current-file-in-new-window to open the current file in a new window. While not addressing everything, it might be better than nothing...

Comment: @MBaas Thanks, I checked there but did not find what I want. Maybe it is not possible to build such an extension?

Comment: It seems nothing is impossible with VSCode - but I haven't reached the extension-coder-level yet...;-)    (Also, I did not link to the marketplace in general, but a specific extension)

Comment: The emacs feature you're describing is called narrowing.  The only thing I could find as far as the term narrowing goes for vscode was a feature request that was auto-closed on github saying that it's a good candidate for an extension.

Comment: @RandyMorris Thanks. I suspect it is not possible. It must be built into VSCODE (Just add another state to +-) https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview